# How can you make functional search bar using Jade and Java?

Tags: java, templates, pug, search-engine

I would like to make a functional search engine where you can search a word and it compares it with a title of a CSV file.
First I tried to make a submit button using JButton and try to combine it with the Jade file. The button was shown but it has no function. These are my two files:

**Java Class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    staticFiles.location("/public");

    CSVParser csvParser;
    Scanner scanner;
    InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("comics.csv");
    csvParser = new CSVParser();
    scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] words = csvParser.parseLine(line);

    get("/search", (req, res) -> {
        JButton buttonA = new JButton("A");
        buttonA.addActionListener(
                (event) -> { buttonAClicked(); } );

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("words", words);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(map, "search");
        return modelAndView;
    }, new JadeTemplateEngine());
}

private static void buttonAClicked() {
    System.out.println("hi");
}

public interface ActionListener extends EventListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}
```

**Jade File:**

html
head
title Search engine
h1 Search

body
p
| Query term (in title)
input(type = 'text' placeholder = 'Query term (title)').
p
input(type='checkbox' id='case sensitivity' name='case sensitivity' value='case sensitivity')
label(for='case sensitivity') case sensitivity

```
  input(type='checkbox' id='whole word' name='whole word' value='whole word')
  label(for='whole word') whole word

  p
  button(onclick = '#{buttonA}') Submit
```